# How to force the last character in a string to be within a certain range?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which allows the value range '1111' - '999999', excluding any instances of '0':

```
^([1-9]){4,6}$
```

This is working for me, except my requirement has been modified. I now have to disallow the last '9' in the range, so that the maximum value of the last character is '8', e.g.

```
1111 - 9998, or 1111 - 99998, or 1111 - 999998
```

How can I modify this regular expression to meet the new criteria?

Comment: WTF? Why downvote this? Is it not a valid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this  one

```
^([1-9]){3,5}[1-8]$
```

Comment: Excellent - one thing though, it needed the range `1-8` rather than `0-8` so I edited the answer to reflect. I have to wait about 7 minutes before I can mark this as correct.

Comment: @DaveDev - `(...)` are not needed

Answer (score 1):

***First option:***

```
^[1-9]{3,5}[1-8]$
```

***Second option:***

```
^(?!.*9$)[1-9]{4,6}$
```

*Negative lookahead `(?!.*9$)` does not allow `9` to be at the end.*

***Third option:***

```
^(?!.*0)(?!.*9$)\d{4,6}$
```

*Negative lookahead `(?!.*0)` does not allow `0` to be in text at all.*